# Executing javascript function before it does its interval

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm currently creating a php page that will be use as a dashboard.  I got many features but one of them kind of annoy me even if it's not that terrible.

Here is the problem: I got a javascript function fetching data in an interval of 5min, so when I open my page I got to wait 5min before seeing my info. Am I stupid and it does work or is there a way to execute my function at the start? Here is a piece of my code:

```
var intervalMeteo = 300000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds, 900000=15 minutes
function doAjaxMeteo() {
$.ajax({
        url: 'sections/meteo.php',
    success: function (data) {
                        //...
    },
    complete: function (data) {
            // Schedule the next
    setTimeout(doAjaxMeteo, intervalMeteo);
    },
    cache: false
        });
    }
setTimeout(doAjaxMeteo, intervalMeteo);
```

Comment: Edit your question and post a [mcve] please, not an image of your code.

Comment: window.onload=doAjaxMeteo; i dont get your question...

Comment: Why aren't you using `setInterval` instead of repeated `setTimeout` calls?

Comment: @ceejayoz because the ajax needs to return before being called again

Comment: @mplungjan Maybe, maybe not. A few seconds here or there doesn't seem like a big deal with a five minute interval.

Comment: @ceejayoz people with a 5 minutes ping ( yes they might exist) will get somewhen an open connections overflow... *its unlikely to happen does not mean one can ignore...*

Comment: @ceejayoz until the interval is changed to 5 secs because stuff changes

Comment: We can come up with edge cases all day long, but in OP's specific example it's probably fine to use `setInterval`.

Comment: @ceejayoz - sure - but then next time he needs 5 secs and does it again with setInterval  - it is better to prevent than to cure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will start it

```
$(function() { 
  doAjaxMeteo(); 
  // do other stuff if needed
});
```

Do not call the setTimeout in the same function, just let the one in complete execute

Also do not use setInterval, instead let the complete execute when it returns

Comment: Why not $(doAjaxMeteo);

Comment: Because there might be more stuff to do